# name variables or append dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, append

I am trying to either 
create dictionaries names based on loop index e.g. mydict_1, mydict_2 etc.
or
append dictionaries in one dictionary

Through a loop I am getting sets of data and I want to be able to access them all at once or one by one.

```
for components in fiSentence.findall("components"):
  operation = components.find('operation').text
  target = components.find('target').text
  targetState = components.find('targetState').text
...
```

all this going in a dictionary:

```
tempDict = {"operation":operation, "target":target, "targetState":targetState, ...}
```

and then outside of the loop I tried to store all of them in another dictionary but I only managed to do so with a list:

```
data.append(tempDict)
```

What I want is either to store them in different dictionaries as:

```
procedural_Step_1 = {"operation":operation, "target":target, "targetState":targetState}
procedural_Step_2 = {"operation":operation, "target":target, "targetState":targetState}
...
```

or
store them all in one dictionary of dictionaries:

```
data = {"procedural_Step_1":{"operation":operation, "target":target, "targetState":targetState}, {"procedural_Step_2":{"operation":operation, "target":target, "targetState":targetState},...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare dict `data` before the loop and in the end of loop:

```
   data['procedural_step_'+str(index)] = temp_dict
```

Index you can get with `enumerate`

Comment: Thank you. It works just fine. I can't believe it was that easy...

Comment: @Spad Magic of Python :)